# Rails Jquery js.erb not reading my instance variables to make comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I am passing a variable @tagging_done that is true or false.  When I put a binding.pry I can see that the variable is there and does have a value.
- When I check if it returns true with tagging_done === true or even tagging_done == true it tells me it returns true but I never reach the true part of the logic.
- When I change it to true == true, it of course executes correctly.

**.js.erb**

```
var tagging_done = "<%=@tagging_done%>";
if (tagging_done === true) {
 alert("here");
} else {
    alert("no here");
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are sending your .js.erb directly, ie. not from your controller where you set up your @tagging_done variable. In my opinion, you should do something like:

```
<script>js_call("<%=@tagging_done%>");</script>
```

from your .html.erb template, and in .js.erb encapsulate the things in a function:

```
function tagging_done() {
  if (tagging_done === true) {
    alert("here");
  } else {
    alert("no here");
  }
}
```

There are a few more issues, like a potential for an XSRF/XSS attack (try to cast the value into a boolean before sending), like this:

```
<script>js_call(<%=!!@tagging_done%>);</script>
```

`!!` is not an operator. It is an operator `!` (ie. negation) applied twice, a common idiom to cast an arbitrary value into boolean.

Another thing is, that you need to ensure that you call your js in html code after your javascript has been loaded. If you use jquery (and you probably do) you can defer its execution after whole DOM tree is ready in a very easy way:

```
<script>$(function(){js_call(<%=!!@tagging_done%>);});</script>
```